# google sheet how to import cells based on value in different cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

So I have two sheets.

Sheet A tab X contains two columns, first one with an url for a google doc and in the other column text IDs.

Sheet B tab Y contains a column with text ID of several more files than Sheet A.

In sheet B i want to import the urls from sheet A in the respective cells in new column matching the text ID.

So urls and text ID matches.

I'm guessing a importrange with query somehow but cant seem to find exactly this issue, any help much appreciated

Comment: ok https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jOYPlyn22RPK9hyPmSQnV3vfaJytvPf7Xix0gdAql2U/edit?usp=sharing here i want it imported to

Comment: exported from https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RM_Wx5UGa76oacD3P0r5WlsozcNuemnsxJwZaDn1_-c/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a couple of formula to resolve your question. There are many precedents for each element of those formula, but none that combine the specific combination of issues in your scenario.

1 - `IMPORTRANGE` - this will return a give range from an external spreadsheet. You include this formula in SheetB and import the URL/ID range from SheetA

2 - `VLOOKUP` - this formula goes in Sheet B, to lookup the ID in Column H in the imported range, and return the URL.

3 - `VLOOKUP - range array`- Vlookup searches in the first column of a range, but the first column of the imported range is the URL, so we use build an array (using curly brackets `{}`) to switch the two columns around.

4 - `IFERROR` - not every ID will have a URL. For those do not, use `IFERROR` to display an appropriate message.

5 - `ARRAYFORMULA` - you've got 300+ lines in sheet B, so use `ARRAYFORMULA` to automatically fill in all the rows from row#5 down to Row 300+

**FORMULAS**

- Step#1

Let's assume that you create a new sheet in Spreadsheet B called `sheeta`. And in Cell A2 of sheeta, you use this formula
`=importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q6AVzkK0NBCebqz2foJ-Uuj6ovAV1HG7AjRUyw2Qp-o/edit#gid=626967951","Sheet1!A2:B7")`

- Step#2
  In SpreadsheetB, Tab Y, use this formula in cell Q6
  `=ARRAYFORMULA(iferror(VLOOKUP(H6:H322,{sheeta!$B$2:$B$7,sheeta!$A$2:$A$7},2,FALSE),"No URL"))`

---

**IMPORTRANGE**

### [image: importrange]

**LOOKUP URL**

[image: URL]

---

Comment: Thank you so much! worked brilliant! Also thanks for explaining well!